# Read excel data using OLEDB: Find blank header cell

Tags: c#, oledb, export-to-excel

I am trying to convert data in excel to JSON using C#. Accepted formats are .xls and .xlsx. OleDbConnection is used to acheive this. Everythig is working as expected, but I should not allow blank values in headers. I use the below code to get header values.

```
dataReader.GetName(index)
```

If any of the header is blank, I get F1, F2, F3.. as the names. Instead of this, I need to know if the header is blank/null so that I can prompt user.

Eg:Like the highlighted cell

[image]

Below is my code:

```
string Import_File = "D:\\input.xls";
string Export_File = "D:\\output.txt";
string connString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Import_File + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1'";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
string sheetName = "Sheet1";        
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connString))
{
    connection.Open();
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("select * from [{0}]", sheetName), connection);
    using (OleDbDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < dataReader.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                //This is the part I am reading the header of each columns
                result.Append(dataReader.GetName(i));

                //Some other processing is done here
            }
        }
    }
}
File.WriteAllText(Export_File, result.ToString());
```

Please Help!!

Comment: In the read header section, try 

`if (dataReader.GetName(i).equals("")) 
`// alert box, or console log

Comment: Nop. 'dataReader.GetName(i).' returns "F1","F2","F3" based on which column header is blank. I have mentioned it above. No blanks or null is returned. I had to go for regex to acheive this for now, but seeking for more optimal solution.